# Numpy sum of values in subarrays between pairs of indices

Tags: python, numpy, sum

Suppose I have an array A. I have a series of index pairs (a1, b1), (a2, b2) ... (an, bn)

I want to obtain all the sums of the elements between those pairs. i.e.

```
sum(A[a1:b1]), sum(A[a2:b2]), sum(A[a3:b3]) ...
```

In terms of run-time, what's the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming your index pairs are stored in a NumPy array `indices` of shape `(n, 2)` and `n` is fairly large, it is probably best to avoid any Python loop:

```
c = numpy.r_[0, A.cumsum()][indices]
sums = c[:,1] - c[:,0]
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
a = np.random.rand(3000)
indices = np.array([[0,3], [9,20], [5,30], [9,33]])
sums = np.add.reduceat(a, indices.ravel())[::2]

assert np.all(sums == np.array([a[i:j].sum() for i,j in indices]))
```

The `cumsum` one above is probably more efficient if there are many indices.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of index pairs and your array is long then caching might be an option. I'd try a recursive approach like

```
CACHE = {}
def mysum(a, b):
    if (a, b) in CACHE:
        return CACHE[(a, b)]

    if a >= b:
        return 0

    s = A[a] + mysum(a+1, b)
    CACHE[(a, b)] = s
    return s
```

Not checked for correctness or efficiency, though. Decreasing the upper index `b` could be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance I'd try the direct solution:

```
[np.sum(A[a:b]) for (a,b) in ab]
```

where `ab` is the sequence of pairs.

`A[a:b]` creates a view on the array; there's no copying of the data involved.

If this turns out to be too slow, please tell us more about the size of `A`, how many pairs of indices you expect to get, whether the `(a,b)` ranges tend to overlap, etc.