# Numpy sum between pairs of indices in 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, sum, multidimensional-array

I have a 2-d numpy array (MxN) and two more 1-d arrays (Mx1) that represent starting and ending indices for each row of the 2-d array that I'd like to sum over. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this in a large array (preferably without having to use a loop, which is what I'm currently doing). An example of what i'd like to do is the following.

```
>>> random.seed(1234)
>>> a = random.rand(4,4)
>>> print a
[[ 0.19151945  0.62210877  0.43772774  0.78535858]
 [ 0.77997581  0.27259261  0.27646426  0.80187218]
 [ 0.95813935  0.87593263  0.35781727  0.50099513]
 [ 0.68346294  0.71270203  0.37025075  0.56119619]]
>>> b = array([1,0,2,1])
>>> c = array([3,2,4,4])
>>> d = empty(4)
>>> for i in xrange(4):
    d[i] = sum(a[i, b[i]:c[i]]) 

>>> print d
[ 1.05983651  1.05256841  0.8588124   1.64414897]
```

My problem is similar to the following question, however, I don't think the solution presented there would be very efficient. [Numpy sum of values in subarrays between pairs of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471474/numpy-sum-of-values-in-subarrays-between-pairs-of-indices) In that question, they are wanting to find the sum of multiple subsets for the same row, so `cumsum()` can be used. However, I will only be finding one sum per row, so I don't think this would be the most efficient means of computing the sum.

Edit: I'm sorry, I made a mistake in my code. The line inside the loop previously read `d[i] = sum(a[b[i]:c[i]])`. I forgot the index for the first dimension. Each set of starting and ending indices corresponds to a new row in the 2-d array.

Comment: Doing a hefty vectorized operation each iteration shouldn't be that slow.  Have you profiled your code and found that the loop overhead is large?

Comment: The summation is typically over 20-30 elements, but is done 1200 times for each function call (1200x1200 2-d array). Also, the function is called around 600 times per simulation, with quite a few simulations performed, so the looping becomes non-negligible.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
from numpy import array, random, zeros
random.seed(1234)
a = random.rand(4,4)
b = array([1,0,2,1])
c = array([3,2,4,4])

lookup = zeros(len(a) + 1, a.dtype)
lookup[1:] = a.sum(1).cumsum()
d = lookup[c] - lookup[b]
print d
```

This might help if your b/c arrays are large and the windows you're summing over are large. Because your windows might overlap, for example 2:4 and 1:4 are mostly the same, you're essentially repeating operations. By taking the cumsum as a per-processing step you reduce the number of repeated operations and you may save time. This won't help much if your windows are small and b/c are small, mostly because you'll be summing parts of the a matrix that you don't much care about. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, this addresses the question when it had a mistake in the code. I've corrected the code and posted the new output, which is what I'm trying to achieve.