# Numpy: How to calculate sums of array slices using indeces?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix M:

```
M = [[10, 1000],
 [11, 200],
 [15, 800],
 [20, 5000],
 [28, 100],
 [32, 3000],
 [35, 3500],
 [38, 100],
 [50, 5000],
 [51, 100],
 [55, 2000],
 [58, 3000],
 [66, 4000],
 [90, 5000]]
```

And a matrix R:

```
 [[10 20]
  [32 35]
  [50 66]
  [90 90]]
```

I want to use the values in column 0 of matrix R as start value of a slice and the value in column 1 as end of a slice.

I want to calculate the sum between and including the ranges of these slices from the right column in matrix M.

Basically doing

```
  M[0:4][:,1].sum() # Upper index +1 as I need upper bound including
  M[5:7][:,1].sum() # Upper index +1 as I need upper bound including
```

and so on. 0 is the index of 10 and 3 is the index of 20. 5 would be the index of 32, 6 the index of 35.

I'm stuck at how to get the start/end values from matrix R into indeces by column 0 of matrix M. And then calculate the sum between the index range including upper/lower bound.

Expected output:

```
[[10, 20, 7000], # 7000 = 1000+200+800+5000
 [32, 35, 6500], # 6500 = 3000+3500
 [50, 66, 14100], # 14100 = 5000+100+2000+3000+4000
 [90, 90, 5000]] # 5000 = just 5000 as upper=lower boundary
```

Update, I can get the indices now using searchsorted. Now I just need to use sum at column 1 of matrix M within the start and end.

```
 start_indices = [0,5,8,13]
 end_indices = [3,6,12,13]
```

Wondering if there is a more efficient way than applying a for loop?

EDIT: Found the answer here. [Numpy sum of values in subarrays between pairs of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471474/numpy-sum-of-values-in-subarrays-between-pairs-of-indices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `searchsorted` to determine the correct indices and `add.reduceat` to perform the summation:

```
>>> idx = M[:, 0].searchsorted(R) + (0, 1)
>>> idx = idx.ravel()[:-1] if idx[-1, 1] == M.shape[0] else idx.ravel()
>>> result = np.add.reduceat(M[:, 1], idx)[::2]
>>> result
array([ 7000,  6500, 14100,  5000])
```

Details:

Since you want to include the upper boundaries but Python excludes them we have to add 1.

`reduceat` cannot handle len(arg0) as an index, we have to special case that

`reduceat` computes all stretches between consecutive boundaries, we have to discard every other one

Comment: @FrancWeser I saw after posting you had mostly figured it out yourself. Still thought the details might be useful.

Comment: Yep very useful, as your way is 2x faster than mine. I'm stuck with a similar problem, do you see any solutions? Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841655/numpy-output-based-on-3-sequential-conditions

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to show an example of the output you are expecting. If what you want to calculate using `M[0:4][:,1].sum()` is the sum of 1000 + 200 + 800 + 5000. Then this code might help:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.matrix([[10, 1000],
 [11, 200],
 [15, 800],
 [20, 5000],
 [28, 100],
 [32, 3000],
 [35, 3500],
 [38, 100],
 [50, 5000],
 [51, 100],
 [55, 2000],
 [58, 3000],
 [66, 4000],
 [90, 5000]])


print(M[0:4][:,1].sum())
```